# What is the number of the parking spot?

Tags: lateral-thinking, pattern

One needs to find the number under the car.

[image: A picture of some parking spaces from the top down, appearing to be numbered "16, 06, 68, 88, ??, 98"]

<sub>Source: unknown</sub>

Comment: Is this original??? I have seen it elsewhere long time ago, it was a classic question for primary schools/ elementary interviews...

Comment: If the source I added earlier today is not the one where you originally found it then you need to provide one you think is satisfactory. This link was the earliest I could find on the web (and was linked to by several other online references), although - clearly - the image is derived from a physical paper of some kind that has been scanned in somewhere. Adding this link earlier today saved this question from being closed by some late 'no attribution' votes-to-close. I advise you to add *a* source, even if you are unable to find *the* source.

Comment: @Stiv, thank you for clarification. The image I think comes from a school test or something like this. I'm not sure. But i'm sure I will not be able to find it's source now. This probably sounds stupid, but I don't want my post/question to contain false information, if the only other option is to close it, then so be it. Meanwhile, I think it must be appropriate for this SE to accept question with unknown authorship and source.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I believe the most obvious answer is:

> There is a usual sequence of numbers, we're just looking at it in the wrong direction. The numbers of the parking spots must be viewed from the outside in, as a driver would see them, which is upside-down from the current view.
>  
>  The shown numbers are: 86, ??, 88, 89, 90, 91. Therefore the answer is **87**.

Answer (score 102):

If you look at the numbers...

> ...upside down, they read 86, __, 88, 89, 90, 91. The number that fits this pattern is, of course, 87.

Therefore, the space as the picture is currently viewed should be filled in with

> **L8**.

Comment: I am conflicted over whether to upvote this.  It made me laugh.  You have plenty of rep, so the positive comment will have to do.

Comment: I was conflicted myself over whether it was better suited as a comment or an answer. The positive comment suffices.

Comment: L8 was my answer also! :)

Comment: Just one comment. Everything you said here is true. But you bolded L8 like it is the answer, meanwhile it is not, since the questions asks for a number of the parking slot, not "what is written there?".

Comment: You can probably tell that this answer was intended to be mostly facetious.

Comment: It hurts when a user earns 700 rep for a joke, while others post lengthy answers and earn just 50-60. `|                                                          |` No, just kidding, go ahead and enjoy your rep.

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code I know that feel as well, don't worry.

Answer (score 12):

The number is:

> 87. Just rotate the image 180 degrees:
>
>  [image: The original image rotated 180 degrees]